# Getting a ClassNotFoundException even though I have the correct jar

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

This is from my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is from my error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook not 

found by poi-ooxml [355]
```

I don't see any error messages on my Spring Tool Suite(very similar to Eclipse), and POI libraries are successfully imported. I really can't understand why am I getting this error.

Also the code runs in an OSGi bundle, and poi jars are deployed along others.

UPDATE: Ok I have found something: The error says:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook not 

found by poi-ooxml [355]
```

But my Workbook.class is inside of poi instead of poi-ooxml. How do I make maven to look inside of poi instead of poi-ooxml?

Comment: Are you running in eclipse or maven?

Comment: is this in a war project?

Comment: I am running a maven project on Spring Tool Suite. So I do maven install. (Updated my question; Eclipse > STS)

Comment: @KalpeshSoni No. 1 api and 1 impl jar is created and they are used along other jars (such as apache-poi) in OSGi bundle.

Comment: Try adding these libraries to your pom file and see if it fixes the problem commons-logging, commons-codec, log4j,
poi-ooxml,poi-ooxml-schemas, dom4j... I think tht you are missing some required libraries

Comment: How are you *launching* the project?

Comment: @chrylis I don't. I just copy the jars to deployment folder, after I do maven install. Then I go localhost:myport/rest/calculate/5/7 and it gives an integer value on the page like this: [12]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear...
Are you using Eclipse when this error occur or maven?

Usually, the best thing is to run

```
mvn clean install
```

in the home directory of *pom.xml* and this will give you a lot more information

Usually when you have an error such *ClassNotFoundException* it means that you miss a dependency in the pom.xml.

Go over all your dependencies and check what is missing in the pom.

Comment: Sorry about confusion. I updated my question. I am using Spring tool suite as IDE, and I do maven install on IDE everytime I changed my code.